# Nginx Conf for Odoo V15 SSL

Tags: nginx, odoo, odoo-15

I would like to have a solution to configure my Nginx for Odoo V15 SSL.

With the configuration following I have an bus.bus error coming with access like erp.mydomain.fr or erp-society.mydomain.fr

I would like to have multiple access to my server from outside.

Waiting for your answer

```
#odoo server
upstream odoo {
  server 127.0.0.1:8069;
}
upstream odoochat {
  server 127.0.0.1:8072;
}

## http redirects to https ##

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name *.mydomain.fr;
    # Strict Transport Security
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=2592000;
    rewrite ^/.*$ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;

}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name *.mydomain.fr;
  proxy_read_timeout 720s;
  proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
  proxy_send_timeout 720s;

  # Add Headers for odoo proxy mode
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

 # proxy buffers
  proxy_buffers 16 64k;
  proxy_buffer_size 128k;

  # SSL parameters
 
  ssl_certificate /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/server.key;
  ssl_session_timeout 30m;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

  # log
  access_log /Users/Logs/odoo.access.log;
  error_log /Users/Logs/odoo.error.log;

  # Redirect longpoll requests to odoo longpolling port
  location /longpolling {
    proxy_pass http://odoochat;
  }

  # Redirect requests to odoo backend server
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

  location /web/static/ {
    proxy_cache_valid 200 60m;
    proxy_buffering on;
    expires 864000;
    proxy_pass http://odoo;
  }
}
```

Conf file from odoo :

```
[options]
addons_path = /Users/xxxxx/Documents/Perso/Programmation/Odoo/15/odoo/addons,/Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/Perso/Programmation/Odoo/15/custom
csv_internal_sep = ,
data_dir = /Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Application Support/Odoo
db_host = localhost
db_maxconn = 256
db_name = xxxxxx
db_password = xxxxxxx
db_port = 5432
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template0
db_user = xxxxx
dbfilter = ^%d.*$
demo = {}
email_from = False
from_filter = False
geoip_database = /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoLite2-City.mmdb
http_enable = True
http_interface = 
http_port = 8069
import_partial = 
limit_memory_hard = 1677721600
limit_memory_soft = 629145600
limit_request = 8192
limit_time_cpu = 9999
limit_time_real = 9999
limit_time_real_cron = -1
list_db = True
log_db = False
log_db_level = warning
log_handler = :INFO
log_level = info
logfile = 
longpolling_port = 8072
max_cron_threads = 2
osv_memory_age_limit = False
osv_memory_count_limit = False
pg_path = 
pidfile = 
proxy_mode = True
reportgz = False
screencasts = 
server_wide_modules = base,web
smtp_password = False
smtp_port = 25
smtp_server = localhost
smtp_ssl = False
smtp_ssl_certificate_filename = False
smtp_ssl_private_key_filename = False
smtp_user = False
syslog = False
test_enable = False
test_file = 
test_tags = None
transient_age_limit = 1.0
translate_modules = ['all']
unaccent = False
upgrade_path = 
without_demo = False
workers = 4
```

Comment: You should share your .conf file maybe you are missing something there.

Comment: I found a beginning of answer, if I access to odoo without :8069, no more error, if i access with server:8069, error Bus.bus, how can I handle that?

Comment: In .conf file there are parameters to specified odoo server port and longpolling port. And maybe your DNS configuration is wrong too.

Comment: please share the error message